# Which type of containers technology apache Hadoop used?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

Does anyone know which containers technology (Docker, LXC,....) is used in apache Hadoop, especially in (HDFS) and (Mapreduce)?
I know its used container technology but I can not find which one in specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box, none. What YARN calls "containers", by default, are bare-metal JVM instances that are scheduled using the YARN NodeManagers.

---

YARN can be *configured* to use [Docker](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/DockerContainers.html) or [runC](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/RuncContainers.html).

Comment: I'm using HDP sandbox, so everything is already configured, but I cannot find which of the conatiners technologies it uses.
I need it for educational research.

Comment: As answered - none. "Container" in YARN is a JVM started with certain memory/heap and CPU allocation.